# Programmatically do shift selection

Tags: emacs, selection, shift

Given a beginning position (b) and an end position (e), I want to perform the same action that one does by hitting the [movement keys with shift](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShiftSelectMode) from b to e, but in elisp.  The selection can be cancelled by any movement key without shift, so [set-mark-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689948) is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
(defun my-mark-region-as-shifted (other-end)
  (let ((pos (point)))
    (goto-char other-end)
    (setq-local transient-mark-mode
                (cons 'only
                      (unless (eq transient-mark-mode 'lambda)
                        transient-mark-mode)))
    (push-mark nil nil t)
    (goto-char pos)))
```

This code is mostly lifted from `handle-shift-selection`.

Comment: This does not work from a batch environment but it works from a regular environment